# Sort ListView after calculating Distance

Tags: android, listview

I have a Json Data where I getting my data. There are many Objects, one of these are Coordinates, latitude and longitude. I have no problems with calculating the distance, displaying on maps etc.

The only thing I want to do is to sort the listview which is created by a customlistviewadapter. So the nearest location should by displayed as the first listview object.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not provided any code ,I assumed you have some model class named MyData which contains distance

```
class Mydata
{ 
  public float distance;
    ....
}
```

and you have an ArrayList of Mydata object by which you created the adapter for ListView.

```
ArrayList<MyData>  data;
```

Now using comparator you can sort the ArrayList, Like this

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<MyData>(){
  public int compare(MyData obj1, MyData obj2) {
    return obj1.distance.compareTo(obj2.distance);
  }
});
```

Now after sort just call notifyDataSetChanged() of the ListView to get updated

```
listview.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Exactly what I did a couple days ago. @Md.Monsur Hossain Ton beat me to it. Good call!